# C++ with random numbers only 0 to 1

Tags: c++

```
#**include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <process.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <random>
using namespace std;
double printMatrix();
int main()
{
    int n = 0, m = 1;
    srand(time(0));
    rand() % 2;
    double printMatrix();
    cout << "Enter the number of rows: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Enter the number of columns: ";
    cin >> m;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
double printMatrix()
{
    return (double)rand() / ((double)RAND_MAX + 1);
}
```

I am really new at C++ and I finally got the prompt for the user to enter how many rows and columns, but it also needs to show this:

```
{Num of rows:3                                                                           Num of col: 2
 01
 00                                                                                       10}
```

Comment: Are you not familiar with using loops?

Comment: Pushing in an X-Y direction: [Consider using `std::uniform_real_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution). It takes a bit of set-up (covered in the link) but does exactly what you want right out of the box (change the example code `std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(1, 2);` to `std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(0, 1);`)

Comment: @CaptainObvlious C++ doesn't have local functions. The declaration refers to a global function, no matter where it is.

Comment: You might want to end the text in your `cout` prompts with a newline, as many implementations won't actually display the text until a newline is sent to output.

Comment: Just noticed that it's `void printMatrix();`. Can't return a number from a `void` function. Try returning `double` instead.

Comment: R Sahu- no I am not familiar with loops, like I said I am very new to C++.

Comment: You seem to be very new to programming in general. What source are you learning from? (I'd expect loops to be somewhere around chapter 2.)

Comment: You're going to have to cast `rand()` to a floating-point type or the integer division will cause the result to always be zero.

Comment: Or maybe returning void is the right call for a function called `printMatrix`. Sounds more like the function should print a matrix than generate a random number.

Comment: @user4581301                                                                                                      Num of rows: 3                                                                                                        Num of columns: 2                                                                                              10                                                                                                                 01                                                                                                                     00

Comment: Whatever you tried to post didn't show up at this end. Regardless, it sounds like something that should be added to the question with an edit.

Comment: @user4581301 That is how the output should look like. I did get the prompt to ask the user how many r & c.

Comment: #include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <process.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

double printMatrix();

int main()
{
 int n = 0, m = 1;
 srand(time(0));
 rand() % 2;
 double printMatrix();
 cout << "Enter the number of rows: ";
 cin >> n;
 cout << "Enter the number of columns: ";
 cin >> m;


 system("pause");
    return 0;
}

double printMatrix()
{
 return (double)rand() / ((double)RAND_MAX + 1);
}

Comment: Sorry it doesn't look right, not used to this site

Comment: By 0 to 1 are you meaning all real numbers 0 to 1 or just integer 0 and 1?

Comment: @LindaS Please edit your question rather than posting in comments.

Comment: The line in your main `double printMatrix();` doesn't do anything, its a **declaration**. If you want to call the actual function you need to write `double num = printMatrix();`.

Comment: @user4581301 just intergers

Answer (score 4):

If You are using C++11, You can use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

static std::random_device rd;  // Random device engine, usually based on /dev/random on UNIX-like systems
static std::mt19937_64 rng(rd()); // Initialize Mersennes' twister using rd to generate the seed

// Generate random doubles in the interval [initial, last)
double random_real(double initial, double last) {
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(initial, last);
    return distribution(rng);  // Use rng as a generator
}

// Generate random int in the interval [initial, last]
int random_int(int initial, int last) {
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(initial, last);
    return distribution(rng);  // Use rng as a generator
}

int main() {
    int rows, columns;
    std::cout << "Enter the number of rows: ";
    std::cin >> rows;
    std::cout << "Enter the number of columns: ";
    std::cin >> columns;
    // For print a binary matrix.
    std::cout << "Binary Matrix" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j) {
            std::cout << random_int(0, 1) << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    // For print a matrix with doubles in interval [0, 1)
    std::cout << "Double Matrix" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j) {
            std::cout << random_real(0, 1) << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Example of an execution:

```
❯❯❯ g++ ../test.cc -std=c++11 -o test && ./test
Enter the number of rows: 3
Enter the number of columns: 4
Binary Matrix
0 1 0 0
1 0 1 0
0 0 1 0
Double Matrix
0.33597 0.384928 0.062972 0.109735
0.689703 0.111154 0.0220375 0.260458
0.826409 0.601987 0.94459 0.442919
```

Comment: I'm thought `fprintf` was not in `<iostream>`.

Comment: Note that `rd()` does not have sufficient entropy to seed `std::mt19937_64`, so you'll be have access to only a small fraction of the possible sequences. i.e.: don't use this seeding method for cryptographic or scientific purposes.

Comment: Caveat: `std::random_device` is implemented poorly and always returns the same number in common Windows versions of GCC. Not a problem for OP as it appears they're using Visual Studio, but future readers be warned.

Answer (score 0):

The standard library has a header called "random".

```
#include <random>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    std::srand(std::time(nullptr));
    int x = std::rand() % 2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: good to mention that srand() should only be called once, only rand() goes in the loop...

Comment: `std::srand` and `std::rand` are from `<cstdlib>` while the non-broken rngs are found in `<random>`

Comment: I am so lost, I don't understand the loop

Comment: @LindaS There are no loops in this answer. It just makes **one** random number between `0` and `1` then exits.

Comment: @Galik how would I make that loop correctly then? I don't fully understand how loops work.

Comment: @LindaS Here is a loop tutorial to study: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_for_loop.htm

Comment: @Galik Thank you